# PHP Extracting a certain part of JSON string where username equals

Tags: php, json, string, where-clause

I was wondering how to extract only a certain part from a JSON String:

```
[
        {
                "ID": "132",
                "countrycode": "DE",
                "USERNAME": "CRC Titan2000",
                "Nickname": "^7[6S] ^1Titan",
                "Money": "550111",
                "Distance": "105692714",
                "Trip": "370839",
                "Bonus": "223",
                "Last Car": "RB4",
                "Last Position": "The Hills",
                "Server": "^7One"
        },
        {
                "ID": "1634",
                "countrycode": "ES",
                "USERNAME": "lobocop",
                "Nickname": "^4Leo ^1Messi",
                "Money": "12816",
                "Distance": "17091463",
                "Trip": "25682",
                "Bonus": "29",
                "Last Car": "MRT",
                "Last Position": "Bridge East",
                "Server": "^7One"
        },
        {
                "ID": "4240",
                "countrycode": "GB",
                "USERNAME": "Smacky",
                "Nickname": "^7^d^6o^7^s",
                "Money": "-532",
                "Distance": "1987579",
                "Trip": "7738",
                "Bonus": "51",
                "Last Car": "RB4",
                "Last Position": "The Hills",
                "Server": "^7One"
        },
        {
                "ID": "5467",
                "countrycode": "TR",
                "USERNAME": "excaTR",
                "Nickname": "^1Furkan^7Tr",
                "Money": "7363",
                "Distance": "17064283",
                "Trip": "15747",
                "Bonus": "31",
                "Last Car": "RB4",
                "Last Position": "Bridge East",
                "Server": "^7One"
        }
]
```

I only want to pull the "Last Position" of the "USERNAME" excaTR, but ignore all the others. Sort of like a MySQL query, where I want to echo the last position WHERE username='excaTR', but instead for PHP and JSON.

This is the code that I tried, but it didn't work

```
$json_stats = file_get_contents('<JSON string here>');
$stats_data = json_decode($json_stats, true);

foreach ($stats_data as $_SESSION['username'] => $location){
    echo $location['Last Position'];
}
```

Comment: You may want to start by having a look at the [foreach documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php). And maybe the help section of this site. Apart from that it is a good idea to provide some further details, not just "it didn't work"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not using `foreach` as it should be.
Have a look at your JSON, you have an array of objects.

So you have to iterate over you array, and check your object values.

By the way, in my answer, I use `json_decode( ,false)` to force result as a multidimensional array, matter of taste only.

```
$json_stats = file_get_contents('<JSON string here>');
$stats_data = json_decode($json_stats, false);

foreach ($stats_data as $array) {
  if ($array['USERNAME'] == 'excaTR') {
    echo $array['Last Position'];
  }
}
```